# Scala - iterate and print a map of maps

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How do I print a map of maps?

I have written

```
map foreach (x => println (x._1 + "-->" + {x._2 foreach {y=> println( y._1 +" ->"+ y._2)}}))
```

It works.
But it looks like a hack.

Is there a better way to write it in Scala.

Comment: Probably because you have everything shoved onto one line. If you space it out, it should look a lot better

Comment: You can just use `println(map)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `println`. It *will print all the nested `Maps`*

```
println(map)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you need to do, you may benefit from actually rendering the full string, then do a single print. See:

```
scala> val mapmap = Map(1 -> Map("a" -> "z"), 2 -> Map("b" -> "y", "c" -> "x")) 
mapmap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map(1 -> Map(a -> z), 2 -> Map(b -> y, c -> x))

scala> mapmap.foldLeft(""){case (x,accX)=> x.foldLeft(""){case (y,accY) => y + accY} + accX}
res0: String = (1,Map(a -> z))(2,Map(b -> y, c -> x))
```

Now res0 is a fully materialized string output, with no side-effects.

Comment: This is a detailed answer, which goes above and beyond what was requested to provide useful insights on how to write more functional code. The negative vote is certainly unnecessary.